# OSX Convert and Network User to Mobile User or force all Network Users to Mobile

Tags: macos, networking, bash-scripting, ldap

We have Macs that I am working on binding to LDAP (not AD) and I want to make sure when a user logs in using their ldap credentials that it either create them a Mobile Account or it runs a script to convert them to a Mobile Account.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: What are you using for the server? What is your current setup? What version of OSX?

Comment: my apologies, should never write one of these while walking out the door from the office...  We are using FreeIPA for an LDAP server.  Some Mountain Lion and mostly Mavericks on the OSX.